# Java Application: Getting Log4j To Work Within Eclipse Environment

Tags: java, eclipse, log4j, slf4j

I've done my best to setup Eclipse and my Java application to use a `log4j.properties` file.  However, it does not seem to be using the properties file and I'm not sure why.

Libraries: slf4j-api-1.6.1, slf4j-jdk14-1.6.1

Within the application the logging works fine.  I am able to print info, warnings, and errors into the Eclipse console.

What I would like to be able to do is change the log level to debug and print all logging messages to both the console and a log file.

I have created a `log4j.properties` file that looks like this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG,console,file
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG, R, O

# Stdout
log4j.appender.O=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender

# File
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=log4j.log

# Control the maximum log file size
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB

# Archive log files (one backup file here)
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.file.File=checkLog.log
log4j.appender.file.threshold=DEBUG

log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.O.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{ISO8601}]%5p%6.6r[%t]%x - %C.%M(%F:%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.O.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{ISO8601}]%5p%6.6r[%t]%x - %C.%M(%F:%L) - %m%n
```

My directory structure looks like this:

```
My Project
--src/
----MYProject/
------*.java
--bin/
----MYProject/
------*.class
--log4j/
----log4j.properties
```

In Eclipse I this this:

*Run Configurations -> Classpath (tab) ->*, right clicked on *User Entries* -> Added "log4j" as a new folder, and saved.

Then in my code I call the logger like this (sample code to demonstrate my approach so it may have syntax errors):

```
package MYProject;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class MyClass{

  final org.slf4j.Logger test_logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);

  public MyClass(){}

  public someMethod(){
    test_logger.debug("Some Debug");
    test_logger.info("Some Info");
    test_logger.warn("Some Warning");
    test_logger.error("An Error");
  }

}
```

I then call `someMethod` and it prints `INFO`, `WARN`, `ERROR` to the Eclipse console.  It won't print `DEBUG` and won't print to a file.

I'd appreciate any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There may be another `log4j.properties` or `log4j.xml` file in the classpath ahead of your `log4j.properties`.  Open the run configuration for your project, and add `-Dlog4j.debug=true` as a VM Argument for your project.  This will instruct log4j to print a lot of additional information on the console, including the config file that it is using.

Comment: I've played around with both your comment and apines and this is what I've figured out.

I cannot add PropertyConfigurator with my current setup because it is a property of the log4j library and not a part of the slf4j-jdk14 (slf4j's log4j binder as I understand it) library.  Setting the VM parameters to true does not return any extra debugging.

Comment: If I then reference the actual log4j library in addition to slf4j-jdk14 I start getting debug output.  Just adding the reference makes my log4j.properties file start working.  This would seem to get me about 90% of what I need.  This increases the debugging but the commands I print out in the given class in the initial post no longer print (test_logger.debug, test_logger.info, etc). I think this is because the log4j library I added is overwriting org.slf4j.Logger that I was previously using.  I'm a little confused on how to get these two libraries to work better together, any suggestions?

Comment: slf4j is just a facade for logging, you still have to add the actual logging library (log4j in your case) to your classpath. See this link: http://slf4j.org/manual.html#binding

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the logging façade **slf4j**, then you need to specify exactly *one* logging backend by including the corresponding jar file for that backend. In your case, you have installed `slf4j-jdk14-x.x.x.jar` on your classpath, which is just a generic logger backend.

In order to use the **log4j** backend, you need to remove `slf4j-jdk14-x.x.x.jar` and replace it with `slf4j-log4j12-x.x.x.jar`. If you don't remove it, slf4j must choose only one backend jar, and probably not the one you want.

Of course you will also need the actual `log4j-x.x.x.jar` file on your classpath too.

Once these jars are properly in place, then the VM parameter of `-Dlog4j.debug` will actually work and be useful in debugging where your logging configs are coming from.

Comment: And when you know what CVE-2021-44228 (a.k.a. Log4Shell) is, you'll be happy that `log4j` was not used by default for your installation.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tell your code to use the properties file. Before any logging is done please put

```
PropertyConfigurator.configure("log4j/log4j.properties");
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have an old version in your target directory.
Clean the project and try again.

Apart from that you should make sure that you **refresh the eclipse project** if you didn't add the log4j.properties via eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

delete jre(JRE System Library) of project in path project properties/library tab and set jre again!

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?